# Why is my ERR trap getting executed for TERM signal?

Tags: bash, terminate

In a bash script, I set two traps: one for the TERM signal and one for the ERR signal.

When I send the TERM signal to the script, it executes the ERR trap, instead of the TERM trap.

I tried it on two computers. In one, Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, the script works fine. In another. Scientific Linux 7.3 (Nitrogen), the error occurs.

Following is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "echo caught signal SIGTERM; exit 1;" SIGTERM
trap "echo caught signal SIGINT; exit 1;" SIGINT
trap "echo caught signal ERR; exit 1;" ERR

set -e
sleep 50

echo grep with err
grep sasas sasasa
```

When I execute `kill -TERM -PID` on the script PID, I get the following:

```
Terminated
caught signal ERR
```

If the `sleep` command ends, I get the following:

```
grep with err
grep: sasasa: No such file or directory
caught signal ERR
```

What could be the problem? How can I force the TERM trap to be executed for SIGTERM signals?

Thank

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack overflow. I've just tried it in git-bash,  running it as `./script.sh &` works as expected, I got `caught signal SIGTERM`. How do you run the script?

Comment: Thanks. Stack overflow has most of the answers for everything already. It's great. I execute it precisely the way you did. Tried it on two Linux boxes. I just tested in with git-bash and it works. Could it be some kind of global setting that my sys-admin set?

Comment: Just checked. Of the three versions of bash tested, the ones that worked were versions 4.3.11(1) from 2013 and  4.4.12(1) from 2016. The one that does not work is 4.2.46(1) from 2011. Does any one know if this could be the issue?

Comment: It must be since you have just tested it :-)

Comment: For curiosity reasons could you try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314556 on the one that didn't work?

Comment: No, it does not work for TERM either. I also checked to make sure the signal numbers weren't changed. `kill -l TERM` returns 15, which is what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

The ERR handler is not called *instead* of the TERM handler. It's called *before*. Both handlers fire consecutively. The reason you don't see this in your example code, is, because your ERR handler has an `exit 1`, so the program exits before the second handler is executed.

In case you don't want to handle TERM in your error handler, you can exclude it by condition. In the trap handler, you can get the signal code via `$?`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

function error {
    if [ "$?" -eq 143 ]; then
        echo "Ignoring ERR, because this actually is TERM..."
        return
    fi
    echo "Handling ERR..."
}

function terminate {
    echo "Handling TERM..."
}

trap error ERR
trap terminate TERM
```

The code received is 143, because codes above 128 mean, it originates from a signal: 128 + 15 = 143

It's not relevant in which order the traps are defined, the ERR handler is always executed before the TERM handler.

The [TLDP describes](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) exit codes 128+n as *Fatal error signal "n"*. So an *error* of type *n*. With that in mind, I guess it makes sense to call the ERR handler before the TERM handler.

Since you mentioned bash versions in your comment, I have not seen any difference in behavior depending on the Bash version. Same thing in bash 4.2.46 and 5.1.8 for me.

Comment: Excellent answer. That said, TLDP is somewhat notorious for being a source of bad-practice examples and outdated advice -- I'd suggest using the Bash Hackers' Wiki and/or the Wooledge BashGuide in favor, when the official manual doesn't suffice.